# Inject Stomp service to a JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, oop, stompjs

I'm using the Stomp.js framework to send and receive data from a Websocket.
So I have to make a class to help the implementation of the Stomp message sender.

Then I made a class bellow:

WebSocket.js

```
function WebSocket()
{
    var host = { protocol: "ws://", url: "localhost", port: ":61623/" }; 
    var hostLocation = hostToString(host);
    var stompVersion = "v11.stomp";
    var username = "admin";
    var pass = "password";

    this.sendMessage = function (paramMsg){
        return wsConnection( hostLocation, stompVersion, paramMsg );
    }

    // make connection with ActiveMQ (WebSocket)
    function wsConnection( hostLocation, stompVersion, paramMsg ) {
        var ws          = Stomp.client( hostLocation, stompVersion );
        var subscribeTopic  = "/topic/event";

        ws.connect( username, pass,
                function() {
                    ws.subscribe(subscribeTopic,
                        function( data ) {
                            return resultChannel(data);
                        }, 
                        { priority: 9 }
                    );

                    ws.send(subscribeTopic, { priority: 9, text: paramMsg }, paramMsg);
                }
            );
    }

    // map the url connection
    function hostToString(object) {
        return object.protocol + object.url + object.port;
    }

    // format the result
    function resultChannel(msg) {
        console.log(msg.body);

        return msg.body;
    }
}
```

Inside the class I try to make a connection with the ActiveMQ using:

```
var ws = Stomp.client( hostLocation, stompVersion );
```

The Stomp object exist inside the class, but the connection not works.

In the HTML I implement that way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMessage(){
        var paramMsg = document.getElementById("mensagem").value; 
        var ws = new WebSocket();
        ws.prototype = Stomp;
        var ul = document.getElementById("textos");

        ul.innerHTML += "<li>" + ws.sendMessage(paramMsg) + "</li>";
    }
</script>
```

Someone know if I did something wrong?

Ps. I imported both JavaScript files.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you have any error messages? `not working` is not enough...

Comment: Just not connect, the class received the stomp stance, but dont connect!